# angular CORS to gist

Tags: angularjs, cors

Hi guys im building an angular app and i have a problem reaching some json that on gist, this is the [json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lukes/ISO-3166-Countries-with-Regional-Codes/master/all/all.json)

When im trying to `$http.get` on this url im getting:

`Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.`

Now i see that Option request is being sent good.
Im using [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) as an auth service.

Things i tried:

```
$http.get(url, {
headers: {
    'authorization': function(conf){
      return undefined;
    }
}}).then(function(data){
       $scope.countries = data;
 });
```

and I also tried to change the url from https to http and i got:
`Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

Now i know that the server need to include in the response header things so i can make that request but the server is not mine :\ so there is no way to modifiy it..
anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that i was sending `Authorization` header by default because of `satellizer`

Satellizer also supports `skipAuthorization` parameter..

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
    skipAuthorization: true})
```

This fix the problem